# How to determine if a YAML document contains a map that has one key but not another key with yq?

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I would like to search recursively through all `.yaml` files in a directory and retrieve the paths to files with this extension that meet some requirements.

I want to get all files that match this requirement: The file contains a `RunningProcess` map that contains a `substring|export` key but no `CmdLine|regex` key. The `RunningProcess` map can occur anywhere in the YAML tree, but the other two keys must be immediate children of the `RunningProcess` map.

I am using [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version 4.35.2.

My terminology might not properly match the terms used in the official YAML specification, so I provide some examples below.

#### Examples

Example 1: The following YAML file should be included in the results:

```yaml
RunningProcess:
  substring|export: true
  otherKey: true
OtherKey: {}
```

Example 2: The following YAML file should not be included in the results, since it contains the `CmdLine|regex` key:

```
RunningProcess:
  substring|export: true
  CmdLine|regex: true
OtherKey: {}
```

Example 3: The following YAML file should not be included in the results, since it does not contain a `RunningProcess` map:

```yaml
OtherKey: {}
```

Example 4: The following YAML should be included in the results:

```yaml
Outer:
  RunningProcess:
    substring|export: true
    otherKey: true
OtherKey: {}
```

#### What I have tried

I know how to write a loop with `find` to try each file at a time (as it seems `yq` does not support recursive searching), so I was focusing on the `yq` query.

I tried the query below, but I get an error message:

```
$ yq eval 'select(has("RunningProcess") and .RunningProcess | has("substring|export") and not .RunningProcess | has("CmdLine|regex"))' test_file.yaml
Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

`not` is a regular filter, use it like `… | not`

```bash
.RunningProcess | (has("substring|export") and (has("CmdLine|regex") | not))
```

With the `-e` flag, yq provides a way to transform its output into an exit status. From the manual:

> `-e`, `--exit-status` set exit status if there are no matches or null or false is returned

Thus, it suffices to take the boolean values from `has` and `not`, and there's no need to `select` the content (unless you want to further process it). Here's one example using this flag in combination with an `if` statement in the shell, and on a file stored in the shell variable `$file`. `stdout` and `stderr` are suppressed to not interfere.

```bash
filter='.RunningProcess | (has("substring|export") and (has("CmdLine|regex") | not))'

if yq -e "$filter" "$file" &>/dev/null
  then echo "$file matches"
# else echo "$file does not match"
fi
```

---

> The `RunningProcess` map can occur anywhere in the YAML document (it doesn't need to be in the root), but the other two keys must be immediate children of the `RunningProcess` map.

Then traverse down the document using `..`, and do the above if there's `any` match: `[.. | …] | any`. Here's the full filter:

```bash
[.. | .RunningProcess | (has("substring|export") and (has("CmdLine|regex") | not))] | any
```

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear enough in my question. The `RunningProcess` map can occur anywhere in the YAML document (it doesn't need to be in the root), but the other two keys must be immediate children of the `RunningProcess` map. I updated my question to state this, and I added a fourth example to illustrate.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Your failed attempt was also only looking on top-level. To traverse the document using the old filter, you could wrap it into `[.. | …] | any`. See my update.